# how to refresh the database data before user enters another word

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu-10.04

I have created an app using django cms called "search", it basically takes a word from the user, search it in 10 xml documents and returns the frequency of the occurrence of that word for each xml file. This data gets stored in the table which I created using sqlite3 database.

Now my problem is that whenever user enters the word the previous data in the table should get deleted without using the delete query but through code snippet . Because this can be easily done by typing delete query on python interactive shell.

But I want as soon as user is directed to the result page which shows the count , if he enters again another word, the previous data should be erased.
Hey this is my views.py code:

```
# Create your views here.
#!/usr/bin/python 

from django.template import loader, RequestContext, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from search.models import Keywords
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as rr

def front_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list
        str1 = request.POST['word'] 
        str1 = str1.encode('utf-8')
        list = []
        path = '/home/pooja/Desktop/'
        fo = open("/home/pooja/Desktop/xml.txt","r")

        for i in range(count.__len__()):
            file = fo.readline()
            file = file.rstrip('\n')            
            find_root_tags(path+file,str1,i)    

            list.append((file,count[i]))

        sorting_list(list)

        for name, count1 in list:
            s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count1)# saving my data in table here .
            s.save()

        fo.close()
        list1 = Keywords.objects.all()
        t = loader.get_template('search/results.html')
        c = Context({'list1':list1,})

        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

    else :  
        str1 = ''
        template = loader.get_template('search/front_page.html')
        c = RequestContext(request)
        response = template.render(c)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

my models.py file :

```
from django.db import models

class Keywords(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    frequency_count = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

Please Help , I'm new to django.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using the delete query but through code snippet." ?

Comment: @Jonas: As I mentioned , we can run the interactive shell and type the sql Query there i.e I can type Query DELETE * from table_name , instead of doing that I want to implement this by writing some code in my either views.py or models.py wherever it is needed to be written , but it should be able to solve the purpose that I mentioned in my question

Comment: please help me at this anyone please.................. it's urgent

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA:please see my updated answer. If this is still not working, share your models.py. Also, share the code where you are saving data in table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to take a look at [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). You can use signal django.db.models.signals.pre_save to delete the data before saving new data. May be [this document](http://www.chrisdpratt.com/2008/02/16/signals-in-django-stuff-thats-not-documented-well/)
can be useful to understand it.

UPDATE:

**First Way:** Not sure *Keywords* is the table in which you are saving your results. If it is the table in which you are saving result then as suggested by Filip Dupanović, Please run the code `Keywords.objects.all().delete()` in **views.py** before the code where you are saving the search result in database table.

**Second Way**: As I told you earlier, we can do this by using signals also. For example suppose my model in models.py is something like this:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Now, before saving any new name in the table, if I want to delete all previous entries, then I can do like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import signals
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def delete_previous_records(**kwargs):
    try:
        Name.objects.all().delete()
    except:
        return False

pre_save.connect(delete_previous_records)
```

Add this code above your for loop where you are saving your data in views.py:

```
try:
    Keywords.objects.all().delete() #Deleting all previous records 
except: 
    return False
#your for loop starts here
for name, count1 in list:
    s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count1)
```

Comment: it's not working , it's giving error: ImportError: No module named new_testmodels.mymodel and I have updated my post please see to it, added one comment to the views.py and shared my models.py code .

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA: Oops my fault. Please remove that line.See my updated code.

Comment: I removed that line becuse I felt that it was irrelevant , but still no effect, any other possible solution

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA: Can you share yourcode where you are saving your table data.

Comment: I have already posted my models.py file code see above, andin views.py file code I have even mentioned the place through comment that where am I storing my data .

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like `Match.objects.delete()` to wipe all the previous results in the view right before you start compiling the new ones.

Comment: :hey i have updated my post , I have included my views.py can you tell me that where should I put your solution?